# Solana keeps showing "baseAccount not provided error" Whats missing?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, anchor-client

I'm trying to call my solana contract from my frontend app.

Even though I added the baseAccount. Solana complains it's not added. Whats going on?

```
const baseAccount = Keypair.generate()


 async function createNFT({ nftPrice, nftRoyalty, nftInfo }) {
// console.log('image', image)
// const added = await client.add(image)
// console.log(
//   '`https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}`',
//   `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}`
// )

const provider = await getProvider()
const program = new Program(idl, programID, provider)
const price = new BN(nftPrice * 10 ** 9)

const result = await program.rpc.mintNft(
  wallet.publicKey,
  price,
  nftRoyalty,
  wallet.publicKey,
  nftInfo,
  {
    accounts: {
      baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
      user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    },
    signers: [baseAccount],
  }
)
console.log('result', result)
}
```

Comment: Share your ```anchor-lang``` code, mainly ```mintNft``` function signature, what's it taking and ```account``` struct.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you haven't updated your IDL to include `baseAccount`.